# cloneNode() issue with Chrome/IE

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem. The following javascript works in Firefox, but is returning nothing is IE and Chrome (both latest versions)

```
var document_copy = document.cloneNode(true);
console.log(document_copy);
```

I am trying to clone the entire html document.

Am I doing something completely wrong?

Update:
@CBroe came up with a work around using

```
document.documentElement.cloneNode(true);
```

Comment: Interesting. I'd expect that to work.

Comment: Is `document` a node though?

Comment: @RGraham: Yes. It's a `Document` node.

Comment: @TimDown You're right, just found [this](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-document)

Comment: _“I am trying to clone the entire html document.”_ – would it be enough for your purpose to clone the `html` node instead …? (`document.documentElement.cloneNode(true)`)

Comment: @CBroe quite possibly. Will try that and see

Comment: @CBroe GENIUS! That works great.

Comment: OK, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

IE 10 works fine for me

---

For chrome it is not implemented yet (*since it was implementation dependent, they chose not to support it*).

See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=258146

Comment: You are right it does work in IE10... must have some other bug here. Interesting about chrome though. Thanks for that. Will have to find a way around this.

Comment: They seem to had implemented it in the past and removed the implementation at some point. Now it looks like they are looking at reverting to that earlier implementation (*so it should come in the future.. not that it helps with your current situation :)*)

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to clone the entire html document.

Clone the `html` node instead – `document.documentElement.cloneNode(true)`